# how to send multiple streams to streaminsight server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, streaminsight

In an intranet setup, I have multiple clients and each one of them is required to send data to StreamInsight server. The data is event-driven, for e.g., when a user clicks on a page, that data (which user clicked on what object) needs to be sent to the streaminsight server.

Also, each client can send a lot of data, so the design needs to be scalable.

I am new to StreamInsight and would appreciate if someone can guide me on how should I send that data from the clients to the StreamInsight server ?

Thanks

PS: Will keep updating this as I find/figure out more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Simms recently [answered a related question on the StreamInsight forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/streaminsight/thread/b9021cb0-1112-4b12-92c0-70978791e879). 
In general, if the event sources are not in the same process as the StreamInsight server, you will need input adapters that can receive serialized event data. That can for instance happen through WCF (see the according [sample on CodePlex](http://streaminsight.codeplex.com/releases/view/46435)) or a TCP/UDP approach.

Regards,
Roman

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is going to be intranet application, so I think TCP would work out well. I am still trying to understand how to "PUSH" data into the Stream Insight server, since most of the examples "PULL" data. Would you happen to know of a sample/link where they PUSH data ?

Comment: If you use the IObservable interface on the input side, you can implement a push model. You can find a [simple example in the StreamInsight blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/streaminsight/archive/2011/01/26/curious-about-iobservable-here-s-a-quick-example-to-get-you-started.aspx).
The "Composing Queries" solution in said sample package uses a data generator input adapter, which creates events based on a timer and pushes them into the engine.